# Cannot access Web API in on-premises VNET using Azure Hybrid Connection

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created an Azure Web App with Hybrid Connection to access Web API on the on-premises machine. When I access the Web API deployed on my local machine (where Hybrid Connection Manager is installed) and connect to it using Hybrid Connection with server/port as *MyMachineName*/*80*, it works perfectly fine.

However, when I try to access the Web API on another server that my local machine is connected to over VNET, it doesn't work. In Hybrid Connection I am giving server/port as *VNETMachine*/*5000*.

The error that I am getting is:

`An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xx.xx.xx.xx:5000`

I ran `netstat -o` and found there is no application using this port and from my local machine where Hybrid Connection Manager is installed, I can access the Web API directly by simply typing in the URL in the browser like

http://VNETMachine:5000/api/author.

Comment: The error message means that the *firewall* is blocking the call, either on your router and/or Windows Firewall on the server. Have you opened port 5000 to other machines? This seems like a networking question, not something related to Azure. Or, you may be trying to make an SSL or TLS call when your site doesn't support it. Did you check the IIS logs? Have you tried troubleshooting IIS, eg by logging the IIS requests?

Comment: No, this is specifically related to Azure Hybrid Connection as the URI I am trying to access is accessible from my machine, however when I try to access it via Azure Hybrid Connection, it throws this error. It may be noteworthy that Hybrid Connection is able access local resources on my machine but not on another server (in On-Premises VNET).